# ListView перекрывает button

Tags: android, listview

Привет! Хочу, чтобы сверху списка была кнопка.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Settings"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItem"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Почему, даже с layout_weight="1", lv перекрывает button?
Помогите реализовать плиз

Comment: именно поэтому и перекрывает. Из за android:layout_weight="1".

Comment: @metalurgus нет, это должно было помочь, но только у кнопки надо поставить layout_weight="0"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Не верю. Не может в данной XML внутри LinearLayout перекрываться Button. Специально только что проверил на девайсе - не перекрывает. Что-то вы не договариваете.

Comment: @anber тем не менее, на предварительном просмотре (вкладка design) все правильно показывает, а на эмуляторе - нет, кнопки не видно

Comment: У меня на эмуляторе работает нормально. Это точно полный текст вашей XML? Добавте в ответ как вы в коде используете это. Какая версия андроид у эмулятора? Такой эффект может быть если у вас несколько лаяутов для одной активити, и вы правите один а на сомом деле отображается другой, либо если в коде что-то динамически меняете.

Comment: @anber да, это полная XML. Эмулятор genymotion, если это важно, версия андроид 4.2.2. В коде ничего динамически не меняю.

Comment: Тогда мои гадания на хрустальном шаре закончились. Если внятных ответов вам не дадут - выложите архив с исходником на какой-нибудь хостинг - я гляну.

Comment: @anber гляньте, плиз https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByDGeRr7y29SSF9mNy1oZVBMVEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: я попробовал убрал  вес вообще - у меня ничего не перекрывает. Хз почему у вас так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ознакомился с вашими исходниками. Как и следовало ожидать у вас в `MainActivity` вызывается вовсе не `activity_main.xml` а совершенно другой лаяут. Более того, вас не смутило что у вас в `MainActivity` вообще не вызывается метод `setContentView()` и вообще не упоминается `activity_main`?
Проблема в том что у вас `MainActivity extends ListActivity` вместо `MainActivity extends Activity`. И как я уже написал нет `setContentView()` - поэтому оно просто отображает вам список и все.

Проще всего исправить так:

1) в MainActivity первой строкой в методе `onCreate()` перенести `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

2) сразу за ней добавить `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

3) В `activity_main.xml` заменить у `ListView` id на стандартный для `ListActivity`: `android:id="@android:id/list"`

**Это для начала, далее:**

Оно и так будет работать, но `activity_main` плохой.

1) в данном случае `layout_weight` вообще не нужен, только прозводительность снижать будет.

2) у `ListView` высота всегда должна быть `match_parent`, иначе ему придется постоянно себе переизмерять чтобы правильно отобразиться на экране, что вообще плохо для производительности.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто поменять у listView

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

на

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: попробовал, не прокатило

Comment: попробуйте сделать - project - clean в eclipse - бывает такая штука, что старый layout.xml закэшируется и никак не обновляется.